# How to match the proper fit with track 2 equivalent data in ATM contactless transaction

Tags: nfc, payment, emv, contactless-smartcard

When i make a contactless transaction, no fit is matched with the card BIN even if the fit is well configured. The ATM use the track2 to match the fit, but since the transaction is contactless, the track 2 is empty. Is there any way to use the track2 equivalent data instead of magnetic data?
FYI: i already specified in the AID configuration to use the track2 equivalent data instead of magnetic data, but still no fit is matched.

Comment: what brand ATM is it?

Comment: Hello @AdarshNanu, it's a wincor

Comment: have you checked the indirect fit state used, there could be one for normal and other for chip

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an ATM software vendor issue. It happens.
ATM is supposed to substitute magnetic stripe track2 with track2 equivalent on EMV transactions.